# WinApi : resize imagelist programmatically

Tags: c++, winapi, icons, imageicon, imagelist

My application use a .bmp file for `ImageList`.
To do this, I use `ImageList_LoadImage` macro (https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/bb761557(v=vs.85).aspx)

I would like to scale this `ImageList` programmatically.
For example, my .bmp file dimension is 72x24 (3 items of 24x24 icons).
And I would like scale it to 144x46 (3 items of 48x48 icons).

I didn't find any `ImageList` function to scale my `HIMAGELIST` handle loaded from .bmp file.

1. I tried using `LoadImage` function (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648045(v=vs.85).aspx)
   But it must be used with bmp file, and here I have `HIMAGELIST` handle.
2. I tried to create a new image, copying scaled icons:

   - `ImageList_Create` (with icons 48)
   - Enumerate icons from image list 24 with `ImageList_ExtractIcon`
   - Scale icon with `DrawIconEx`
   - Add to new image list with `ImageList_AddIcon`
     But it fails when addin icon to new image list.

Comment: Load the small bitmap (`LoadImage`). Create a bitmap of the desired size (`CreateComptaibleBitmap`). `StretchBlt` the former into the latter. Now create the list around it, with `ImageList_Create` followed by `ImageList_Add` or `ImageList_AddMasked`

Comment: Note that `StretchBlt` creates very poor results though. Calling `SetStretchBltMode(hdc, HALFTONE)` makes it marginally better. I suggest using GDI+ or another library that provides a choice of filtering algorithms for scaling.

Comment: Thanks for answer.

Comment: Do you mean I should use 'StretchBlt' on HICON extracted from small bmp imagelist, and then get a new HICON to add to new image list (big one)?
If you have link about use of 'StretchBlt' to change HICON, thanks in advance.